# Laravel eloquent query slow with 100000 records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this simple eloquent query, works fine, but with few records.
When database increments until 100000 records become very slow.

I read should be use chunk instead of get. How can I implement it for this query?

```
$collection = Contact::with('shop');
$collection = $collection->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
$collection = $collection->get();
$json = $collection->map(function ($contact) {
    return [ 
        'id' => $contact->id,
        'name' => $contact->name,   
        ...about 50 columns more.
        'shop' => [
                'id' => optional($contact->shop)->id,
                'name' => optional($contact->shop)>name
        ],  
        ...about 6 relations more.
    ];
});
$json = $json->paginate(50);
return response()->json(['contacts' => $json], 200);
```

Comment: Why `->get()` 100000 records when you `->paginate(50)` later on? Paginate right away instead of `get()`

Comment: When I use 'paginate' before 'map' don't show pagination. I'm using Laravel/Passport

Comment: Do you need to join table `shop` in your query?

Comment: Yes I need. I removed all fields from array only for show example.

Comment: Use paginate and then use a transformer. With Laravel you can use Resource Collections. You shouldnt be using map. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting getting all the data like 1M or how many records it has. Then you are mapping it and paginate it and getting only 50. There is huge performance problem with your code.

You can directly call like this:

```
return response()->json(['contacts' => Contact::with('shop')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(50)], 200);
```

If you only need id and name for contacts:

```
return response()->json(['contacts' => Contact::select('id', 'name', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(50)], 200);
```

Comment: I need to create a custom json with 'map' after query. How can I do it in this way?

Comment: As far as I can see you are using Contact id and name. So you do not need shop relation and you can just use select id and name. I updated my answer.

Comment: You are right, I did not specify that I removed all fields from the array just to give the example. My original code has about 50 columns and 6 relations.

Comment: Oh that I didn't know. Then you definitely should not use map etc. If you can make it just do it on mysql or your frontend.